# WCF Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled + Content Type error

Tags: .net, wcf

That Metadata error is what I get when I browse to the service in a browser.  I am not consuming it with a client

and Yes.. I added `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>`, and I have a mex endpoint defined

but it still won't work..

So I created a barebones service to host on IIS7. Fresh install of Windows 7 and VS2010.

I had followed the instructions of this page to the letter:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx

I'm convinced that this has to be some sort of configuration issue with IIS7 but and not sure.  Here's my service setup:

EDIT:

I tried accessing the service with svcutil and got the following error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
```

it also says: `The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.`

not sure how to resolve it, however..

.svc file:

`<%@ServiceHost language="C#" Debug="true" Service="DestructionServices.TacticalNukeSVC`"%>

.cs file (located in the C:\Development\HostedDestructionServices\App_Code folder):

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace DestructionServices
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface INukeInterface
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string FireMissile();

        [OperationContract]
        string DirectFire(double x, double y, double z);

        [OperationContract]
        void EnterCoordinates(double x, double y, double z);
    }

    public class TacticalNukeSVC : INukeInterface
    {
        public string FireMissile()
        {
            return "Boom";
        }

        public void EnterCoordinates(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            //bah, who cares about coordinates..
        }

        public string DirectFire(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            return "Fired at: " + x + ", " + y + ", " + z;
        }
    }
}
```

Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="DestructionServices.Destro" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="DestructionServices.INukeInterface" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" httpHelpPageEnabled="True" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

[image: IIS]

Comment: also, adding a baseAddress node gets ignored by IIS

Comment: yes, if you host in IIS, specifying a base address is moot, since IIS will dictate where your service lives...

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Your code and config seems fine - except for one little point:

In your `<service>` tag, you have defined a name that doesn't seem to correspond to the class that actually implements your service:

```
<service name="DestructionServices.Destro"  ......>
               **************************
```

but your class is:

```
namespace DestructionServices
{
    .....
    public class TacticalNukeSVC : INukeInterface
    {
```

Those names need to match! The `name=` attribute on the `<service>` tag in config **must be** exactly what your service class is called - fully qualified, including namespace - so in your case here, it should be:

```
<service name="DestructionServices.TacticalNukeSVC" ......>
```

Comment: That was exactly it.  Thanks Marc. :)

Comment: Thanks Marc, I was going mad. I was experiencing the same problem and I had spent at least a day on it.

Comment: Wow this fixed it for me too, couldn't figure out why I was still getting the mex binding missing error when it was there. Thanks and +1!

Comment: The .svc file, the web.config and the very DLL must all point to the same name.  In my case one namespace was shorter - I believe Visual studio resolves it through some project name space or so; but when I copied it to another machine/win/iis-configuration it stopped. Thx for your help.

Comment: it is case sensitive as well

Comment: +100 Votes. My service name was correct, but was coming from a different assembly. I wasn't using a AssemblyName.ServiceName, instead just using ServiceName.

Answer (score 2):

Previously working WCF with nice~ settings stopped working and shows - error- Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.

THOUGH MEX Settings are perfect, still WCF shows above error, reason: The virtual directory created from VS IDE IS NOT Created, though it gives "success" message..

Just Create Virtual Directory in IIS manually , Bingo error is resolved.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar issue. I had the wrong namespace in my service tag in web.config as against the namespace for the service class in the svc file.

***web.config***

```
< service name="X.Y.Z.ContentService" behaviorConfiguration="XServiceBehavior">
```

***svc file***

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="X.Y.A.ContentService" %>
```

As seen above, service tag in web.config had namespace X.Y.Z where the svc file had X.Y.A.

(Thanks to Marc)

Answer (score 0):

I had another issue. I have an IIS asmx application, and inside I've placed a subfolder with svc. Configured it properly, but it didn't give me the metadata until I found this in web.config in **parent** directory:

```
<system.web>
  <webServices>
    <soapExtensionTypes>
      <add type="SPFWebService.SPFWebServiceExtension,App_Code" priority="1" group="0" />
    </soapExtensionTypes>
  </webServices>
</system.web>
```

Fixed it by removing my new service to a separate directory.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a class with no default constructor an another constructors , then add an empty default constructor , I had the same issue and i resolved it by this .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. For anyone that might come across this later. My problem was that my service interface did not have the [ServiceContract] DataAnnotation

```
[ServiceContract] //<--This was missing
public interface IServiceInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Foo(Bar bar)
    //...
}
```