# WCF Metadata not showing

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I've followed [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the letter, however after navigating to the service address (http://localhost/IISHostedCalc/Service.svc) I got to a page that starts with the following message:

> Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.

In the bottom of the page there are instruction on how to enable metadata publishing but without success.
I also tried to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4917761/1092181) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734765%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but it didn't work.

This is how my service looks like:
C:\IISHostedCalcService\service.svc:

```
<%@ServiceHost language=c# Debug="true" Service="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService"%>
```

C:\IISHostedCalcService\App_Code\Service.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface ICalculator
  {
     [OperationContract]
     double Add(double n1, double n2);
     [OperationContract]
     double Subtract(double n1, double n2);
     [OperationContract]
     double Multiply(double n1, double n2);
     [OperationContract]
     double Divide(double n1, double n2);
  }

  public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
  {
     public double Add(double n1, double n2)
     {
        return n1 + n2;
     }
     public double Subtract(double n1, double n2)
     {
        return n1 - n2;
     }
     public double Multiply(double n1, double n2)
     {
        return n1 * n2;
     }
     public double Divide(double n1, double n2)
     {
        return n1 / n2;
     }
  } 
}
```

C:\IISHostedCalcService\App_Code\Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService"
      behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />

        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

IIS version is 7.5:
[image: iis]

Is it possible that my web.config file is being ignored (or at least parts of it) or is it something else?
**EDIT** I completly removed the `web.config` file from the app_code folder and still got to the exact same page so I guess that my `web.config` is being ignored. any way to solve it?

Comment: When you open the page in your browser, besides the message "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled." it shows some more information, like suggesting to enable httpGetEnabled or add a serviceBehavior?

Comment: It does, I mentioned it in the body of the question right after the error message

Comment: Shouldn't it be http://localhost/IISHostedCalc/CalculatorService.svc ?

Comment: @NeillVerreynne nice catch although this is exactly what the [msdn tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says i should do in section 11. the results are the strangely the same.

Comment: Ok, let's  check if your configuration is being used. Comment the service tag (the entire <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService" tag and endpoints). It will remain <system.serviceModel>
    <services></services>.
In behavior tag, remove the name (name="SimpleServiceBehavior"), it will be <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>.......</behavior>. Try to browse your service again

Comment: @RicardoPontual please see my edit

Comment: I'm wondering if your web.config file is at right place..in your edit it wrote your web.config was in your app_code folder, but it must be in same folder as your .svc file. Your service folder just need .svc and web.config files and a bin folder with your binaries.

Comment: @RicardoPontual that was it, and as a side note, the url that i test the service should contain the same name as the svc file name. put this in an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be the Web.config location.

Try to put both .svc file and web.config files in same folder, that's why configurations are correct, but not applied.