# WCF Service Library (IIS): Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, web-config

I receive this error and I cannot shake it. This question is similar to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917761/wcf-metadata-publishing-for-this-service-is-currently-disabled-content-type-er) question and quite a few others, not to mention the page itself.

Yes, I am fully cognizant that the `namespace` and `service name` MUST MATCH EXACTLY. I read that a zillion fold now.

I have a WCF Service Library, which I am running in IIS. The server is a Windows Server 2016 Standard edition. I renamed `App.config` to `Web.config`, though I tried as `App.config`. I tried what seems like a zillion configurations of each and still the same error. Yes, I tried adding in binding and specifying `basicHttpBinding`.

**Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>

        <services>
            <service name="MyTesterLibrary.MyTester" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyTesterLibrary.IMyTester" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>

        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" httpHelpPageEnabled="True" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Main Class**

```
namespace MyTesterLibrary
{
    public class MyTester : IMyTester
    {
        public string GetVersionInfo()
        {
            Backup.GetVersionInfo(out string response);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**Interface Class**

```
namespace MyTesterLibrary
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyTester
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/GetVersionInfo")]
        [OperationContract]
        string GetVersionInfo();
    }
}
```

**ProductServiceHost.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="MyTesterLibrary.MyTester" %>
```

I followed instructions on another site and created the IIS site. This screenshot says it all.

[image: IIS Showing WCF website]

I know that in the referenced SO article, the guy was insistent that the problem was in IIS and it was not, but my problem sure seems that way. I just tried `basicHttpBinding` again and the same.

[image: Browser page showing metadata for this site disabled message]

[This question](https://forums.asp.net/t/1970132.aspx?WCF%20Metadata%20publishing%20for%20this%20service%20is%20currently%20disabled) on the asp.net forum was interesting too. I instinctively renamed `App.config` to `Web.config` and rebuilt the DLL. IIS does not read `App.config'.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That last referenced article stated the problem and my suspicion was correct. I am leaving this question here as I wrote it up nicely, but more importantly an IMPORTANT fact was not stated.

Either `Visual Studio` or `C#` does not embed Web.config OR IIS does not pull the file from the DLL. All the articles that I read talk say to write a SVC file, place the DLL in the bin file, but all leave out two crucial pieces of information.

1. Copy `App.config` to `Web.config'.
2. Place a copy of `Web.config` in the same folder as the SVC file.

There is no need to refresh the website in IIS, but one does have to refresh the browser page.

I hope that this answer helps someone, as I really suffered and almost did not get it.